# Uploading a document manually to a SharePoint document library using Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model

I have been searching for a way to upload a document manually to a SharePoint document library using Jquery. i have done it in C#, but i want to do the same in Jquery. Still i couldn't find the way, but i am trying. Please anyone would help me to get this stuff done. Any guide is appreciated.

Basic logic what i did in C# is shown below, how would i do the same thing in Jquery. I am using SharePoint 2010 and my browser is IE9

```
string filename = fileBrowser.FileName;  

Stream fstream = fileBrowser.FileContent;

SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(filename, fstream, replaceExistingFiles);
```

Comment: No obviously it is not. In there it is all about a plugin, but i want do it manually.

Comment: Well since you have the source code for the upload "plugin" there, I still think you find your answer there..